# CDockingManager GetPaneList() causes assertion failure in wincore.cpp?

Tags: c++, user-interface, mfc

So I thought this would be pretty simple, but I forgot it's MFC. Instead of registering a notification listener for data model changes that would possibly require a GUI update on each individual control I figure why not register it once and then send a message to all the open dock panes and allow them to update their controls as needed on their own terms for efficiency.

My callback function for handling the notification from the server looks something like this:

```
void CMainFrame::ChangeCallback(uint32_t nNewVersion, const std::vector<uint32_t>& anChangedObjectTypes)
{
    CObList panes;
    GetDockingManager()->GetPaneList(panes); // assert failure

    if (!panes.IsEmpty())
    {
        POSITION pos = panes.GetHeadPosition();
        while (pos)
        {
            CDockablePane* pPane = dynamic_cast<CDockablePane*>(panes.GetNext(pos));
            if (pPane)
                pPane->PostMessage(DM_REFRESH, nNewVersion);
        }
    }
}
```

The error I am getting is an assertion failure on line 926 of wincore.cpp

```
CHandleMap* pMap = afxMapHWND();
ASSERT(pMap != NULL); // right here
```

There is a comment below this saying this can happen if you pass controls across threads however this is a single threaded MFC application and this is all being done from the main frame.

Does anyone know what else can cause this?

If there is another way to go about sending a message to all the open `CDockablePane` derived windows in MFC that works as well ...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's the obvious workaround that I didn't want to have to do but after hours of debugging and no response here I guess this is a viable answer:

I added `std::vector<CDockPane*> m_dockList;` to the members of `CMainFrame`

Now after each call to `AddPane` in various places that can create and open new dock panes I make a subsequent call to `push_back` and then I override `CDockablePane::OnClose` like so:

```
CMainFrame* pMainFrame = reinterpret_cast<CMainFrame*>(AfxGetMainWnd());
if (pMainFrame)
{
    std::vector<CDockPane*>::const_iterator found(
        std::find(pMainFrame->DockList()->begin(), pMainFrame->DockList()->end(), this));
    if (found != pMainFrame->DockList()->end())
        pMainFrame->DockList()->erase(found);
}
CDockablePane::OnClose();
```

Now this list will only contain pointers to open dock panes which allows me to handle the event notification in my callback and simply do a for loop and `PostMessage` to each.